# Move next Dateadd to Monday if it falls on Saturday or Sunday

Tags: vba, excel

Please I would like to move next date added always to Monday if it falls on Saturday or Sunday using VBA macro. I would prefer not to use formulas. The following code make date added fall anytime in the week. Many thanks for your help really appreciated. Plese let me know if the question is not clear and I would try to reformulate. Thanks again.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, d3 As Date

    d1 = DateAdd("w", 1, Date)
    d2 = DateAdd("w", 7, Date)
    d3 = DateAdd("w", 3, Date)

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("H3:H150")) Is Nothing Then
        If target.Value = 7 Then
            target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d2
        ElseIf target.Value = 3 Then
            target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d3
        ElseIf target.Value = 1 Then
            target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d1
        Else
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Look at using the `WEEKDAY` function to get whether you need to add a day or 2.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the function that checks for Saturday or Sunday, is called `Weekday`. 0 is Sunday, 6 is Saturday. You can use it with the built-in enumerators in `VBE`, to make sure that everything is ok:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print Weekday(Now) = vbMonday
    Debug.Print Weekday(Now) = vbTuesday

End Sub
```

The first day of the week is an optional argument in the `Weekday()` function, set by default to `vbSunday`:

[image]

---

However, I am pretty sure that the [NetworkDays() formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7) would do really well.

It is built with the idea to ignore Saturdays and Sundays.
Here is a small example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintNetworkDays()

    Dim dtStartDate     As Date
    Dim dtEndDate       As Date
    Dim rngHolidays     As Range

    dtStartDate = DateSerial(2017, 7, 1)
    dtEndDate = DateSerial(2017, 8, 1)

    Set rngHolidays = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

    rngHolidays(1, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 5)
    rngHolidays(2, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 6)
    rngHolidays(3, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 7)
    rngHolidays(4, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 8)
    rngHolidays(5, 1) = DateSerial(2017, 7, 9)

    Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(dtStartDate, dtEndDate, rngHolidays)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help

```
Function NextMonday(dtDate As Date, lngDaysToAdd As Long)

Dim intDaysOffset As Integer

NextMonday = DateAdd("d", lngDaysToAdd, dtDate)

intDaysOffset = (7 - Weekday(NextMonday, vbMonday)) + 1

NextMonday = DateAdd("d", intDaysOffset, NextMonday)

End Function
```

Comment: Please how can I make it work with my previous code? Thanks a lot .

Comment: `d1 = NextMonday (date,7)`

Comment: Thanks I have tried it. I have readjusted the code in this way:

Comment: Can you please show me more in detail how to do it as I have added the function with your code

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: What is the error, and what is happening?  I get the correct results?  Have you added the code to yours?

Comment: Thanks Nathan I have tried again and it works ok. The only thing is that the function move always the date to the next monday. If for example I add 7 days send me to the 31/07/2017 or only 1 day to 24/07/2017. Do you know why please? My aim is to move date to next monday only if my date falls on saturday and sunday. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Look at the code, it doesn't use anything other than `dateadd` and `weekday` you've 2 things to research, have a go.  May be quicker than keep typing and getting me to assist.  Unless you can post your complete data source, columns etc, how it wants to be etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will going to have a look. Thanks for your assistance. Have a good day.