# Can I change date to Monday if date equals Saturday or Sunday in Excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

When I run my excel VBA macro it automatically copies a sheet called temp into a new sheet formatted "day of week-month-day-year" "ddd-MMM-dd-yyyy"
It will name this new tab with tomorrows date.
But when I run this on Friday or Saturday it will use Saturday or Sunday for the Date.
When ran on Sunday it will use Monday which is good.

I have tried using code from this StackOverflow post and mix it into my code without any luck.
[Move next Dateadd to Monday if it falls on Saturday or Sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162396/move-next-dateadd-to-monday-if-it-falls-on-saturday-or-sunday)
Not exactly sure how to make it work with my code.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Format(Date + 1, "ddd-MMM-dd-yyyy")
```

I need it to always use Monday if ran on a Friday or Saturday.

Comment: *I have tried using code...without any luck*  <-- what does this mean, exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: IOW, show us what you have tried, and explain what you mean by "without any luck"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = format(Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(date, 1), "ddd-MMM-dd-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Sub CopySheet()

    Dim strName As String

    If Format(Date, "dddd") = "Saturday" Then
        strName = Format(Date + 2, "ddd-MMM-dd-yyyy")
    ElseIf Format(Date, "dddd") = "Sunday" Then
        strName = Format(Date + 1, "ddd-MMM-dd-yyyy")
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = strName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Weekend_Dates()

    Dim k As Integer

    For k = 1 To k + 1

        If Weekday(Cells(k, 1).Value, vbMonday) = 1 Then
             Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1)
        ElseIf Weekday(Cells(k, 1).Value, vbMonday) = 2 Then
             Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1)
        ElseIf Weekday(Cells(k, 1).Value, vbMonday) = 3 Then
             Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1)
        ElseIf Weekday(Cells(k, 1).Value, vbMonday) = 4 Then
             Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1)
        ElseIf Weekday(Cells(k, 1).Value, vbMonday) = 5 Then
             Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1)
        ElseIf Weekday(Cells(k, 1).Value, vbMonday) = 6 Then
             Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1) + 2
                Else
                Cells(k, 2).Value = Cells(k, 1) + 1
             
        End If

    Next k

End Sub
```